# Timestamp with utc and any other timezone is coming out to be same with arrow

Tags: python, arrow-python

```
import arrow    
print arrow.utcnow()
print arrow.utcnow().timestamp
print arrow.utcnow().to('Asia/Kolkata')
print arrow.utcnow().to('Asia/Kolkata').timestamp
```

I need the timestamp (in int) of 'Asia/Kolkata' timezone, which is +5:30 from utc.

`arrow.utcnow()` and  `arrow.utcnow().to('Asia/Kolkata')` are coming out to be different and the second one is +5:30 the first, as expected.

However,  `arrow.utcnow().timestamp` and `arrow.utcnow().to('Asia/Kolkata').timestamp` are still coming out to be same.

I am sure I am missing something very basic here, but can anyone explain this?

Comment: `timestamp` is UTC.

Comment: Okay, so how should I get number of seconds from Jan 1 1970, in my local time?

Comment: Added suggestion to my answer.

Comment: @KshitijMittal you almost certainly shouldn't.

Comment: @KshitijMittal it would be helpful to explain why you think you need the timestamp (which by definition is in UTC) in a local time.  There might be better methods in Arrow (and general good practices working with local times) to acheive your end result.  Can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: OK - check my answer, it should give you the result you need: take a UTC date, convert to Kolkata time (+5:30) but then treat that as UTC.

Comment: Alternately, if it's always Kolkata time,you can just add 5.5 hours to the timestamp by adding 5.5 * 3600 (the number of seconds in the timezone offset)

Comment: So, the reason why I am using this is I am using an API. It takes start and end timestamps. Earlier, I was using this code to generate current timestamp: int((datetime.now() - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()

However, when I changed it to arrow.utcnow().timestamp, I realized, it takes the difference of number of seconds in Asia/Kolkata timezone, instead of utc.

Comment: What is the API? And how do you know it doesn't take UTC timestamps, since timestamps are generally UTC?

Comment: The API returns data generated for increasing timestamps. When I send it the utc timestamp, it returns data of 5.5 hours less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "timestamp", by definition, is always in UTC:

> The Unix time (or Unix epoch or POSIX time or Unix timestamp) is a
>   system for describing points in time, defined as the number of seconds
>   elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of
>   January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds.

If you take your localized time string, convert it to a UTC date time (that is, 5pm Kolkata time becomes 5pm UTC), then you can get a timestamp that corresponds to the local clock time.  Example:

```
import arrow    
print arrow.utcnow()
print arrow.utcnow().timestamp
kolkata = arrow.utcnow().to('Asia/Kolkata')
print kolkata.replace(tzinfo='UTC').timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamps are UTC, this is also described in the Arrow docs

> **timestamp**
>
> Returns a timestamp representation of the Arrow object, in
>   UTC time.

Arrow will let you convert a non-UTC timestamp into arrow time but it won't let you shoot yourself in the foot by generating non-UTC timestamps for you.

> `classmethod fromtimestamp(timestamp, tzinfo=None)`
>
> Constructs an Arrow
>   object from a timestamp, converted to the given timezone.
>
> Parameters:    timestamp – an int or float timestamp, or a str that
>   converts to either. tzinfo – (optional) a tzinfo object. Defaults to
>   local time. Timestamps should always be UTC. If you have a non-UTC
>   timestamp:
>
> `arrow.Arrow.utcfromtimestamp(1367900664).replace(tzinfo='US/Pacific')
>   <Arrow [2013-05-07T04:24:24-07:00]>`

The full docs are here:

http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/